# Can I query per hour increment of a accumulation column in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to save event time and the total amount of generated electric per 30 seconds. The total amount is not reseted to zero everytime. It's just the total from the meter first started to now, not total amount generated in the 30 seconds.

Is there any way of querying daily, weekly or monthly aggregations on the total amount of generated electric column (Maybe not just sum or avg)?

Or by design a `AggregatingMergeTree` table?

I don't need to keep every record, just need the daily, weekly and monthly aggregations.

For example :

```sql
create table meter_record (
   event_time Datetime,
   generated_total Int64
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*UPDATE*

Prefer to use [SimpleAggregateFunction](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/836ac810a7a5696449aa70b4a120c0c0f00e1582/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00915_simple_aggregate_function.sql) instead of [AggregateFunction](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/data_types/nested_data_structures/aggregatefunction/) for simple functions like *median*, *avg*, *min*, *max* to speed up aggregates calculation.

---

Let's suggest you need to calculate *median*, *average* and *dispersion* aggregations for this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE meter_record (
   event_time Datetime,
   generated_total Int64  
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY (toYYYYMM(event_time))
ORDER BY (event_time);
```

Use [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/aggregatingmergetree/#creating-a-table) to calculate required aggregates:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW meter_aggregates_mv
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(day)
ORDER BY (day) 
AS
SELECT  
  toDate(toStartOfDay(event_time)) AS day, 
  /* aggregates to calculate the day's section left and right endpoints */
  minState(generated_total) min_generated_total,
  maxState(generated_total) max_generated_total,
  /* specific aggregates */
  medianState(generated_total) AS totalMedian,
  avgState(generated_total) AS totalAvg,
  varPopState(generated_total) AS totalDispersion
  /* ... */
FROM meter_record
GROUP BY day;
```

To get required daily / weekly / montly (and any day-base aggregation like *quarterly* or *yearly*) aggregates use these queries:

```sql
/* daily report */
SELECT 
  day,
  minMerge(min_generated_total) min_generated_total,
  maxMerge(max_generated_total) max_generated_total,
  medianMerge(totalMedian) AS totalMedian,
  avgMerge(totalAvg) AS totalAvg,
  varPopMerge(totalDispersion) AS totalDispersion
FROM meter_aggregates_mv
/*WHERE day >= '2019-02-05' and day < '2019-07-01'*/
GROUP BY day;

/* weekly report */
SELECT 
  toStartOfWeek(day, 1) monday,
  minMerge(min_generated_total) min_generated_total,
  maxMerge(max_generated_total) max_generated_total,
  medianMerge(totalMedian) AS totalMedian,
  avgMerge(totalAvg) AS totalAvg,
  varPopMerge(totalDispersion) AS totalDispersion
FROM meter_aggregates_mv
/*WHERE day >= '2019-02-05' and day < '2019-07-01'*/
GROUP BY monday;

/* monthly report */
SELECT 
  toStartOfMonth(day) month,
  minMerge(min_generated_total) min_generated_total,
  maxMerge(max_generated_total) max_generated_total,
  medianMerge(totalMedian) AS totalMedian,
  avgMerge(totalAvg) AS totalAvg,
  varPopMerge(totalDispersion) AS totalDispersion
FROM meter_aggregates_mv
/*WHERE day >= '2019-02-05' and day < '2019-07-01'*/
GROUP BY month;

/* get daily / weekly / monthly reports in one query (thanks @Denis Zhuravlev for advise) */
SELECT
  day,
  toStartOfWeek(day, 1) AS week,
  toStartOfMonth(day) AS month,
  minMerge(min_generated_total) min_generated_total,
  maxMerge(max_generated_total) max_generated_total,
  medianMerge(totalMedian) AS totalMedian,
  avgMerge(totalAvg) AS totalAvg,
  varPopMerge(totalDispersion) AS totalDispersion
FROM meter_aggregates_mv
/*WHERE (day >= '2019-05-01') AND (day < '2019-06-01')*/
GROUP BY month, week, day WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY day, week, month;
```

Remarks:

- you point that raw-data is not required to you just aggregates, so you can set engine for *meter_record*-table as [Null](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/null/), manually clean *meter_record* (see [DROP PARTITION](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/alter/#alter_drop-partition)) or define the [TTL](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/create/#ttl-expression) to do it automatically
- removing raw-data is bad practice because it makes impossible to calculate new aggregates on historical data or restore exist aggregates etc
- the materialized view *meter_aggregates_mv* will contains only the data inserted in the table *meter_record* after creating the view. To change this behavior use [POPULATE](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/create/#create-view) in view definition

Comment: group by rollup able to cacl this by one select

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev thank you for the idea, I extended the answer

Comment: Sorry, I did not say clearly. The generated_total column is not amount generated in the 30 seconds. My question has edited.

Comment: @xiemeilong I fixed the answer to take into account your remark

Comment: Your method maybe loss amount when cross days. For example,  the value of generated_total got at 23:55:45 is 1000,  and the second day 00:00:15 is  1100. The amount bewteen 1100 and 1000 will not included in any day.

Comment: @xiemeilong It should work correctly because is calculated the [intermediate state of aggregations](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/combinators/#agg-functions-combinator-state) not resulting values. You can test it.

Comment: @vladimir Sorry，I did not  try your solution and switched to other works. I tried it today, the issue in my last comment exists.

Comment: @vladimir The issue can be solved by using the `neighbor` or `runningDifferenceStartingWithFirstValue` function. I learned how to use the feature of clickhouse from your answer. Thank you very much.